# Pushing sample/ buffers from AppSink to AppSrc

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I need to implement an architecture where I can push data from AppSink to 
Appsrc. 
Now, I can't figure out if it can be done within the same pipeline or I 
would need two pipelines to achieve this. Considering I am somehow 
manipulating the data between apppsink and appsrc.

Another thing is, from AppSink I can extract samples using pull-samples, and to AppSrc push-sample or push-buffer can be used to put data. So, is there a way I can generate a buffer of received samples in AppSink explicitly or I should feed sample by sample to the AppSrc?

Please suggest.

Comment: So you need to write your custom element instead.

Comment: Do you mean what I'm asking can't be achieved with AppSink and AppSrc?

Comment: And even if I have to, can you head me towards a good reference or tutorial?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why so you need that construct? Perhaps a Pad Probe can do this easier?

Comment: A Sample also has a Buffer. So you would Pull a sample, get the buffer and pass it it to the source. Maybe requires an increased reference on the Buffer Object. Not sure though.

Comment: I'm trying to have a pipeline which will read udp stream at one port  and then I need to decode the frames, apply some modifications to the received frame, re-encode it and then forward it to some another port. So to extract frame out of pipeline, where I'll modify the frame, I need AppSink and then to push the modified frame back in pipeline I need AppSrc. Is there any alternate way I can achieve the same? Please suggest

Comment: So, is it like there is one buffer per sample? (correct me if I'm wrong).     And sample do have the buffer, but AppSink has no pull-buffer signal, it only allows pull-sample.

Comment: A Buffer is Part of a Sample. A Sample offers more than a Buffer but you Care about the Buffer only. But i suggest to check out pad probes. You can intercept Buffers in your transcoding Pipeline and modify them with these without Using appsrc and appsink.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the other thing I might bring up here is the computation I need to do over a video frame may involve heavy processing algorithm. So as whole, I'll extract incoming frame, apply algorithm, modify frame and put it back in pipeline. And this needs to be done for every video frame gstreamer receives. Do you think, pad probes could help me achieve this?

Comment: It wont magically fix your computation demand. As long as you accept your computation latency and set your queue sizes big enough you should be okay. The same applies to the appsrc approach. If your computation ist Not Realtime how can possibly Help you anything in fixing that?

Comment: Well, Thanks for the detailed explanation. As per documentation it seems like it allows modify buffers. I'll try using pad probes and check if it fits my requirements.